# How do i create an svg element with Raphael js?

Tags: svg, raphael

`jQuery("div")` will create a jquery object with div element in it.
Similarly how can we create a "`clipPath`" element in Raphael js.

Raphael has defined methods for rectangle,circle. Is there any method like `RaphaelCreateElement("clipPath")` or `RaphaelCreateElement("defs")` which will return a Raphael element.So that i can do `paper.add(RaphaelCreateElement("clipPath"))`.

I had a look into this [How do I manipulate the SVG DOM and create elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320002/how-do-i-manipulate-the-svg-dom-and-create-elements), but the returned element is svg dom element, it doesn't enjoy all the Raphael methods.

Answer (score 0):

I've responded a question here ([adding ID's to raphael objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461716/adding-ids-to-raphael-objects/8536743#8536743)) in wich you are going to find the answer.