# SVG use - add to group

Tags: javascript, svg

**PROJECT**

I'm including a SVG in my project using `<use ...></use>` as follows:

```
<use xlink:href="myMap.svg#status-map"></use>
```

When inspected in the browser this produces:

```
<svg id="status-map" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1247.244px" height="907.087px" viewBox="64.094 122.25 985.889 657.072" enable-background="new 0 0 1247.244 907.087" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="road">...</g>
  <g id="river">...</g>
  <g id="station">...</g>
  etc etc etc
</svg>
```

**PROBLEM**

What I need to do is to group the inner `<g></g>` elements so the code becomes:

```
<svg id="status-map" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1247.244px" height="907.087px" viewBox="64.094 122.25 985.889 657.072" enable-background="new 0 0 1247.244 907.087" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="container"> // <-- new container
    <g id="road">...</g>
    <g id="river">...</g>
    <g id="station">...</g>
    etc etc etc
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've tried extracting and wrapping it with `innerHTML` but this fails with SVG files/code.

**ALSO TRIED**

I also tried simply putting the `<use>` in the `<g>` element but that doesn't work either.

**The reason I need to do this is I'm using [SVGPAN](https://code.google.com/p/svgpan/) to allow me to zoom in and out, and drag...this requires the inner `<g>` elements to be wrapped in an outer**

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Just put the `<use>` in the `<g>` element.

Comment: What you see in the inspector is he shadow DOM. SVGPAN probably won't work as those inner `<g>` elements don't exist in the page DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate svg's DOM with JS:

```
var svg   = document.getElementById("svg");
var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

var e = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'g');
e.setAttribute('id', 'container');

while(svg.firstChild) {
  e.appendChild(svg.firstChild);
}

svg.appendChild(e);
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NtwUnNnBMyQSD6728pTq?p=preview)

Refer to [How do I manipulate the SVG DOM and create elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320002/how-do-i-manipulate-the-svg-dom-and-create-elements)