# make svg element be on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to make some svg elements to be on top . Something like Z-Index. I know that svg z-index is set by their draw order. I can change their order by deleting svg elem and redraw it again. So I am doing it "hard way" . Is there better way to do this using vanilla JS / JQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use z-index in svg elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements)

Comment: no I know that solution. I just want to know more effective way

Comment: What are you doing currently?

Comment: what I wrote ...  delete svg element and append it again on svg field

Comment: did you check [How do I manipulate the SVG DOM and create elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320002/how-do-i-manipulate-the-svg-dom-and-create-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to delete the element and recreate it.  You can just move it.

First, get a pointer to it, and its parent SVG:

```
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
var myelement = document.getElementById("myelement");
```

Then use `insertBefore()` to insert it at the end.  If you "insert" a node that is already part of the DOM, it gets moved instead.

```
mysvg.insertBefore(myelement, null);
```

Using `null` here means insert it as the last child.

**Demo**

```js
function moveIt()
{
  var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
  var myelement = document.getElementById("myelement");

  mysvg.insertBefore(myelement, null);
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="75" r="75" fill="green" id="myelement"/>
  <circle cx="200" cy="75" r="75" fill="red"/>
</svg>

<button onclick="moveIt()">Move it</button>
```

**Update**

The jQuery equivalent of the moveIt() function would be:

```
function moveIt()
{
  var mysvg = $("#mysvg");
  var myelement = $("#myelement");

  mysvg.append(myelement);
}
```

Comment: is there something similar in JQ?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the answer with the jQuery version of the `moveIt()` function.  However please note that, in general, jQuery is not suitable for manipulating SVG elements.  Many jQuery functions do not work with SVG.