# Dynamically created SVG elements are not rendered by the browser

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to use SVG markup in my HTML in order to render some graphics. The problem was very tricky because I just realized that the issue is when generating the SVG programmatically.

#### The markup

What I want to end up in my page is this fragment of code:

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15"></circle>
</svg>
```

If you take this and paste it inside a page, all is fine and the a black circle is rendered!

#### Creating the SVG dynamically

But I want to create this content using Javascript, so I have this:

```js
var container = document.createElement("div");
var svg = document.createElement("svg");

var circle = document.createElement("circle");
circle.setAttribute("cx", "20");
circle.setAttribute("cy", "20");
circle.setAttribute("r", "15");

svg.appendChild(circle);
container.appendChild(svg);
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

Well, try to execute this in fiddle or in your browser and you'll see it will not be rendered. When you inspect the HTML, you see that the `circle` is not taking any space.

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I manipulate the SVG DOM and create elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320002/how-do-i-manipulate-the-svg-dom-and-create-elements)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you have to use `"document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");"` to create svg elements

```js
var container = document.createElement("div");
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle.setAttribute("cx", "20");
circle.setAttribute("cy", "20");
circle.setAttribute("r", "15");

svg.appendChild(circle);
container.appendChild(svg);
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

Comment: I tried in `svg` but I thought that it was not needed in `circle`... I see thanks. But why is it needed in `circle`? The `xmlns` in `svg` is a globally included ns, so it should work on all nested elements...

Comment: you have to create svg dom elements from svg namespace (`"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`) by calling `document.createElementNS` instead of `document.createElement`

Comment: Yes I understand that. So, what I tried is invoking the `createElementNS` on the `svg` element only. It did not work as it looks like, by your answer, that I also need `createElementNS` on the `circle` element as well. Well, my question is: why is it not enough only on `svg`? When you use `xmlns` on the svg element, everything inside that element will see the schema, so no need to specify `xmlns` on `circle` as well...

Comment: @Andry the namespace of an element is set on creation and is not altera ble afterwards.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637811/how-can-i-add-a-svg-graphic-dynamically-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: In 2018, is it still required that we use the name space "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg". When rendering in HTML I do not need to, it just seems messy and expensive.

Comment: @Andry, please see my answer below, I solved it without calling `createElementNS()` on child elements.

Answer (score 2):

While you have to use `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");` to create the parent svg element,
you are not strictly required to use that method for the child elements to get a functioning graphic on your page. Calling `createElementNS()` for each child could become especially cumbersome if you are using a more complex image, with multiple paths, defs, style, title, etc, for example something exported from a drawing program.

A quicker way that worked well for me, is to create the parent svg element, and then add all its contents in one go as `innerHTML`. Your specific example could be solved like so:

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var svgContent = '<circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15"></circle>';

svg.innerHTML = svgContent;
container.appendChild(svg);
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: what is this? the asker wants it to be generated dynamically, this is wrong

Comment: This appears to be nothing more than copying part of the question and does not answer anything. It is also missing the mandatory XML namespace declaration to be a correct solution.